# bootstrap modal blackout background for a second and then auto corrects

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have used bootstrap modals and when the modal loads it black out the background completely for a second and then auto corrects. I didn't get whats going on (also if I use a fresh modal that is also doing the same). Here's my [website](https://koltepatilvervegoregaon.com/). You can find the modal at Enuire Now/ Brochure .... and many more links that open that modal. And one more thing I've 2 modals in total (1 auto popup- unique and the other is linked to many buttons).[Blackout Background ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GkOg.png), [after a second & which I want ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H19WR.png). Also I've used bootstrap 3.3.0 and modal bootstrap 3.4.1 but using one by one didnot work. If I use only modal on codepen or offline it works fine

I'm not good to define question/problem. Feel free to help me or to improve my question clarity.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've some questions here
1. When you try using `modal bootstrap 3.4.1`, does it work correctly?
2. Why you can't use 2 modals from `modal bootstrap 3.3.0`? Maybe you're not defining the ID/labels/attributes correctly, it should be totally different for both as long as has different purposes.

Comment: Hii thanks for your help I'got a lead (error is in my header when I delete all the link and add only one bootstrap version modal works fine), but still searching to fix it. Although yes I tried only using one bootstrap verion but that also didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I'll share answer if I found it:)